# Read google public calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to read the RSS feed of google Calendar.  It is publicly available in a site.
How get the events of calendar through RSS feed?

Comment: Finally i found solution.... If someone want to know reply

Comment: could you please tell solution? I want to get the public calendar for a specific country.

Comment: @Sam In such a case, please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Using Google Calendar API JSON Output

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=insertAgenda&orderby=starttime&max-results=15&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true
```

> This retrieves the full projection of the public feed for the developer-calendar@google.com calendar in JSON format (alt=json-in-script) with a callback function called insertAgenda. A maximum of 15 events is returned (max-results=15), recurring events are represented as individual events (singleevents=true) and all events in the future (futureevents=true) are returned in ascending order (sortorder=ascending).

Source: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample says that version of the API is no longer supported and redirects to new one.